# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON" when making API request in React frontend to Node.js backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json

I'm building a web app with React and Node.js, where you can enter a Spotify playlist link and it would search for the songs on YouTube and download MP3s. I'm getting this error message:

> Error fetching playlist tracks: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON SpotifyDownloader.js:17

Here's my SpotifyDownloader.js file:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './SpotifyDownloader.css';

const SpotifyDownloader = () => {
  const numberOfCircles = 10;
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('');
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);

  const handleSearch = async () => {
    // Send searchQuery to your backend API endpoint to fetch playlist tracks
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`/api/playlist/${searchQuery}`);
      const data = await response.json();
      setSearchResults(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching playlist tracks:', error);
      setSearchResults([]);
    }
  };
```

And this is my index.js file:

```
// index.js (backend)
const express = require('express');
const SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const fs = require('fs');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
  clientId: 'clientId',
  clientSecret: 'clientSecret',
});

// Authenticate with Spotify API
spotifyApi.clientCredentialsGrant()
  .then((data) => {
    console.log('Connected to Spotify API');
    spotifyApi.setAccessToken(data.body.access_token);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error connecting to Spotify API:', error);
  });

const youtube = google.youtube({
  version: 'v3',
  auth: 'key',
});

// Fetch playlist tracks from Spotify API
app.get('/api/playlist/:playlistId', async (req, res) => {
  const { playlistId } = req.params;

  try {
    const { body } = await spotifyApi.getPlaylistTracks(playlistId);
    const songTitles = body.items.map((item) => item.track.name);

    const videoIds = [];
    for (const title of songTitles) {
      const response = await youtube.search.list({
        part: 'id',
        q: title,
        type: 'video',
      });

      if (response.data.items.length > 0) {
        videoIds.push(response.data.items[0].id.videoId);
      }
    }

    res.json(videoIds);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching playlist tracks:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});

// Download audio from YouTube as MP3 file
app.get('/api/download/:videoId', (req, res) => {
  const { videoId } = req.params;
  const audioStream = ytdl(videoId, { quality: 'highestaudio' });

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'audio/mpeg');
  res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename=${videoId}.mp3`);

  audioStream.pipe(res);
});

const PORT = 3001; 
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

Why is this not working? What changes do I need to do for it to work? I'm still a beginner so I can't make much sense of this.

I think the response I'm getting is not in JSON format. When I check under the Network tab I'm getting it as Status Code 304. I've no idea what to do to fix the error and make sure my program works.

Comment: 304 means the page content hasn’t changed so the browser uses a previously cached copy, this is normal.  However your api call is returning html instead of json.  You need to read the html that it’s returning, it’s probably telling you about an error.